# offline video upload youtube 3.0 api php

Tags: api, video, upload, youtube, offline

We have been using the API version 2 but have a new account we want to push videos we create to.  It appears that we now need to use API version 3 for this new account but can't seem to find a way to push the videos to an account that is offline.  Does anyone know if there is a way to push videos to an account with the new api that doesn't require user interaction.  Is there a long term access token available?